# No parameterised reduction for a problem indicates FPT or not?

Tags: np-hard, parameterized-complexity

I am currently working on **parameterized complexity**, especially on the hard proofs. There is a problem that I am currently working on, denoted by $P$ and a parameter $x$, I discovered that there is no parameterized reduction for $P$ w.r.t the parameter $x$ from any *W*-class. I have tried to give a reduction from a *W*[2]-hard, Dominating set problem parameterized by the solution size but got to know that due to the problem definition of $P$ and the structure of the parameter $x$, it is not possible. In fact, the reduction from any *W*-class is not likely to exist. My question is: What does this indicate? Does it mean the problem is *fixed-parameter tractable* (FPT) or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Proving that there is no such reduction would only establish that the problem is not $W[2]$-hard. But that just means that the problem is not complicated in one particular fashion, it doesn't mean that the problem is easy. There are problems that are not $W[1]$-hard but are far, far from  being FPT.

However, it would really surprise me if a somewhat natural problem is neither FPT nor $W[1]$-hard.

So given what you know about your problem, I'd expect the problem to be FPT; and you probably should try and prove that next.

Comment: Since, i have a proof that there does not exist a parameterized reduction from any $W$-class to $P$, doesnt this serve the purpose of proving that the problem is in FPT?

Comment: @BalchandarReddy No. As I explicitly state in my answer, being "not $\mathrm{W}[1]$-hard" doesn't imply anything at all about the problem being easy. The problem could even be noncomputable in the parameter.

Comment: I was able to prove that there won't be a parameterized reduction from any W[i]-class to the problem $P$. Doesnt this imply FPT?

Comment: @BalchandarReddy Why do you keep asking the same question over and over?

Comment: I think i misunderstood in some way, could you please let me know in which class the problem might fall other than in FPT? probably some figure might help in understanding better. TIA.